# BOLT CM - Exclude contenttype listing from routing

Tags: php, content-management-system, bolt-cms

Is there a way to exclude contenttype listing from routing?

**Example**

I have a contenttype like this:

```
pages:
name: Pages
singular_name: Page
description: Create Page
class: \Bolt\Extension\Animal\Translate\Content\LocalizedContent
fields:
    <<: *record_defaults
    <<: *content_defaults
    <<: *seo_defaults
    <<: *template_defaults
    sort:
        label: Sort
        type: integer
        group: Configuration
sort: sort
```

My routing config looks like this:

```
contentlisting:
path: /{contenttypeslug}
defaults:
    _controller: controller.frontend:listing
requirements:
    contenttypeslug: controller.requirement:pluralContentTypes
```

The **pages contenttype** does not have a contentlisting view, but the routing is getting rendered internally. I know this, because I can see it in the sitemap.xml

```
<url>
 <loc>http://ghostar.local/en/pages</loc>
 <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
 <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
```

the contenttype has a config attribute "viewless". But when I insert this, the **record pages** will not appear in sitemap.xml (e.g. /page/about-me) as stated in the documentation: [Bolt Resource Contenttype](https://docs.bolt.cm/3.4/howto/resource-contenttype)

How to fix this? I can not make a separate contentlisting routing for every contenttype, because internally, it prepares the listing routing.

**Bolt: V.3.4.10**

**Extensions: Bolt/Sitemap, Animal/Translate**